# drop temp table not take effect for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a query script in SQL server management studio which is as below:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  drop table #temp
select somecolumn into #temp from sometable where somecondition

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  drop table #temp
select somecolumn2 into #temp from sometable2 where somecondition2
```

I add the *drop* table line to ensure the #temp table is cleaned from the cache. However, for repeated running the script, I still got error as "here is already an object named '#temp' in the database." in the second *select* line. It seems that the drop table didn't take effect as I wish.

Comment: because you cant use the same name for a temptable in one query. just rename the temp table and it would do the trick.

Comment: and actually it takes effect the compiler just doesnt accept duplicate names for temptables.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 if you look carefully OP is actually dropping the temp table before creating it again. it should work all he needs is a batch separator between these two blocks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  drop table #temp
select somecolumn into #temp from sometable where somecondition

GO   --<-- Separate these two block with a batch separator 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  drop table #temp
select somecolumn2 into #temp from sometable2 where somecondition2
```

Comment: In fact I had tried that and I thought the many names a little ugly. OK if this is the only elegant way.

Comment: @anaconda_wly you should accept the answers that help you solving your problem, I just looked at your other questions that you have asked on Stackoverflow and you havent accepted any of the answers. please do so , so people feel appreciated when they solve your problems for you thank you.